# Unit Testing of actions

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

If I need to **Unit Test** my actions, how do I do it? Do I need to use /test/bootsrap/ for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional tests is what you need to write.
They do exactly what you need:

It calls your action with different parameters and test your response.

Comment: There's one redirect to external resource in my scenario which makes functional test sequence split. Also my actions class has a lot of private methods to send / receive data. This data is critical, so I think it would be good idea to have Unit Tests for the internals of my app.

Comment: A good practice is to move as all methods that are not controller related to your lib directory. So you can test them with a unit test.